# Require all and AllowOverride for Root and Specific Folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I want to disable access and .htaccess override everywhere on my server except where my websites reside - web and public_html folders. I've tried doing it like this:

```
<Directory />
    Require all denied
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory ~ ^/home/user/(web|public_html)>
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

But I found out that regular expressions are not allowed in this setup: "AllowOverride is valid only in Directory sections specified without regular expressions, not in Location, DirectoryMatch or Files sections." So I separated the two.

1. Is it correct? Is there a better way to compose this?

```
<Directory />
    Require all denied
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory /home/user/web>
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory /home/user/public_html>
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

2. Since I'm disabling access and .htaccess files everywhere except in the folders of my websites, are there any other places on Apache (CentOS) that require access and .htaccess to function, like `/usr/local/httpd` or other? Will this impair server functioning?
3. Also, is it allowed to use syntax like this, without spaces and new lines: `<Directory />AllowOverride None</Directory>`? I have a lot of single directives applied to single folders and it would be easier to format them like this than to do standard line breaks and indents.